# Java_after popup error,layout is freezing and doesn't working

Tags: java, android, popup, alert

I making android application,I need error popup in one moment and when popup is showing and I click OK,popup is closing but main layout is dark and doesn't work,it is freezing.
please see my code,Can I refresh or reactivate this layout?
I need any solution for this.
please help and thank you

```
 package com.example.granturismo.binaryconverter;
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.calculate:
                try {
                    EditText decimal = findViewById(R.id.decimal_value);
                    EditText binary = findViewById(R.id.binary);
                        Dialog dlg = new Dialog(this);
                        dlg.setCancelable(false);
                        dlg.setTitle("Please Input Any Number");
                        dlg.show();
                    int decimal_value = Integer.parseInt(decimal.getText().toString());
                    List<Integer> binary_nums = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                    String result = "";
                    int nashti = 1;
                    for (int i = decimal_value; i >= 2; ) {
                        binary_nums.add((i % 2));
                        i = i / 2;
                        nashti = i;
                    }
                    binary_nums.add((nashti % 2));
                    for (int i = 0; i < binary_nums.size(); i++) {
                        result += "" + binary_nums.get(i);
                    }
                    binary.setText(new StringBuilder(result).reverse().toString());
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                AlertDialog.Builder alert=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                alert.setTitle("Error");
                alert.setMessage("Please Input Any Number");
                alert.setCancelable(true);
                alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        dialogInterface.cancel();
                    }
                }).show();
            }
                break;
            case R.id.clear:
                EditText decimal1=findViewById(R.id.decimal_value);
                EditText binary1=findViewById(R.id.binary);
                decimal1.setText("");
                binary1.setText("");
                break;
            case R.id.shecvla:
                Button shecvla=(Button) findViewById(R.id.shecvla);
                TextView convertSign=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.convertSign);
                if(shecvla.getText()==getString(R.string.dectobin)) {
                    shecvla.setText(getString(R.string.dectobin));
                    convertSign.setText(R.string.bintodec);
                }
                else{
                    shecvla.setText(getString(R.string.bintodec));
                    convertSign.setText(R.string.dectobin);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: my theory is to remove `dlg.show();` because you met with a crash in the middle and pop appears and previous dialog is still there `dig.show`

Comment: no,problem is in catch,not in try

Comment: have you tried what i suggest because i see the issue right here `Integer.parseInt(decimal.getText().toString())`

Comment: WOW!!!!I removed dlg.show() and it works.